# Using `require` in directives in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Getting an error while using require in angular directives.

This is my html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <superman speed>This is a superhero</superman>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app is:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('superman',function(){

    return{
        restrict:'E',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.abilities=[];

            $scope.addspeed=function(){
                $scope.abilities.push('Speed');
            }

        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                console.log(scope.abilities);    
            })
        }
    }
})

myApp.directive('speed',function(){
    return {
        require:'superman',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs,supermanCtrl){
            supermanCtrl.addspeed();
        }
    }
})
```

The error I am getting is supermanCtrl.addspeed() is not a function.
I also logged my supermanCtrl and it did not contain addspeed function. Any details why this is happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$compile Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) injects the `this` context of the controller as the fourth argument to the linking function. It does not inject the `$scope` object.

From the Docs:

> ### require
>
> Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference (require)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Use the `this` context of the directive controller to define controller methods:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('superman',function(){

    return{
        restrict:'E',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.abilities=[];

            $scope.addspeed=function(){
                $scope.abilities.push('Speed');
            }
            //-------------------------------
            //USE `this` context
            this.addspeed = $scope.addspeed;
            //-------------------------------
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                console.log(scope.abilities);    
            })
        }
    }
})
```

```
myApp.directive('speed',function(){
    return {
        require:'superman',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs,supermanCtrl){
            supermanCtrl.addspeed();
        }
    }
})
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/RMLUzHUMNJRGEOm29ibG?p=preview)

---

> suppose we have large number of functions, so we have to do this.addspeed = $scope.addspeed; everytime. Isn't there any shorter way?

If you don't need the function on `$scope`, just bind directly to the `this` property:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('superman',function(){

    return{
        restrict:'E',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.abilities=[];

            //$scope.addspeed=function(){
            //BIND directly to the `this` property
            this.addspeed = function() {
                $scope.abilities.push('Speed');
            }
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                console.log(scope.abilities);    
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but still one small question, suppose we have large number of functions, so we have to do  this.addspeed = $scope.addspeed; everytime. Isn't there any shorter way? Don't know if it makes sense